# How to design WPF in HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, wpf

I am new to WPF technology but expert in web technologies.
I am wandering around to find whether it is possible to design WPF apps front end in HTML, javascript and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to learn XAML to design the front end of your WPF applications.

Comment: No hack is made. Like phonegap is made for android apps to build front-end in html css javascript etc

Comment: There might be some 3rd party utility to do what you need, but I'm unaware of it.  XAML is pretty simple to learn especially if you know XML or similar.

Comment: Yes it is but for awesome design I have to spent too much time on xml.
I have a strong grip on HTML, CSS and javascript

Comment: There are a few HTML to XAML converters available they are just not very reliable.  Depending on the complexity of your design it may work and it may not.  It's best just to use the right tool for the job.